# Omegle Java API Doesn't Work

Tags: java, api, captcha, recaptcha

I am attempting to use the Omegle Java API found here: https://github.com/nikkiii/omegle-api-java. However, the following code:

```
package me.nrubin29.pollmegle;

import org.nikki.omegle.Omegle;
import org.nikki.omegle.core.OmegleMode;
import org.nikki.omegle.core.OmegleSession;
import org.nikki.omegle.core.OmegleSpyStranger;
import org.nikki.omegle.event.OmegleEventAdaptor;

import java.util.Map;

public class Pollmegle {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Omegle omegle = new Omegle();
        final String question = "Yes or no?";
        System.out.println(question);

        try {
            OmegleSession session = omegle.openSession(OmegleMode.SPY_QUESTION, question, new OmegleEventAdaptor() {
                @Override
                public void chatWaiting(OmegleSession session) {
                    System.out.println("Waiting for chat...");
                }

                @Override
                public void chatConnected(OmegleSession session) {
                    System.out.println("You are now watching two strangers talk about \"" + question + "\"!");
                }

                @Override
                public void spyMessage(OmegleSession session, OmegleSpyStranger stranger, String message) {
                    System.out.println(stranger + ": " + message);
                }

                @Override
                public void spyDisconnected(OmegleSession session, OmegleSpyStranger stranger) {
                    System.out.println("Stranger "+stranger+" disconnected, goodbye!");
                    System.exit(0);
                }

                @Override
                public void question(OmegleSession session, String question) {
                    System.out.println("Question: "+question);
                }

                @Override
                public void omegleError(OmegleSession session, String string) {
                    System.out.println("ERROR! " + string);
                    System.exit(1);
                }

                @Override
                public void recaptchaRequired(OmegleSession session, Map<String, Object> variables) {
                    System.out.print("Required // ");
                    for (String var : variables.keySet()) {
                        System.out.println(var + " // " + variables.get(var));
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void recaptchaRejected(OmegleSession session, Map<String, Object> variables) {
                    System.out.println("Rejected // ");
                    for (String var : variables.keySet()) {
                        System.out.println(var + " // " + variables.get(var));
                    }
                }
            });

            System.out.println("Session " + session.getId() + " created.");

            omegle.setEventParseDelay(1000);
            omegle.run();
        }
        catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
}
```

Yields this result:

> Yes or no?
>
> Required // 6Led7gkAAAAAAEAyh-Kt7HTb_oC0chDvQIZ8VtQb // null
>
> Session central1:znv479i7a5sh2u60z5sg6s2nzm6jpb created.

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to pass a captcha?

Comment: You're probably better off raising an issue on the github project: https://github.com/nikkiii/omegle-api-java/issues

Comment: That project hasn't been touched in 9 months, but I guess I could submit an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem isn't the API, it's that my IP address was flagged and I needed to enter a reCAPTCHA every time I started a chat. It works.

Answer (score 0):

no, its supposed to output this. but when i ran the code i kept getting "enum not found errors" so i went into `org.nikki.omegle.core.OmegleEvent` and added the lines

```
,statusInfo,identDigests
```

to the bottom and it worked like a charm. Are you getting the same enum not found errors?

Comment: I did before, but then I added `statusInfo` and I didn't get any more errors. I just now added `identDigests` but that didn't help.

Comment: @pogostick29 are you getting an exception??